# Navbar responsive tiene valores que no deben ser en sus versiones desktop y movil

Tags: javascript, html, css, css3

Tengo el siguiente `navbar`, sucede que le aplique un `margin` de 10% a la izquierda y la derecha porque así quiero que se vea en la versión `desktop` pero cuando esté en la versión `responsive` (Por debajo de 768px de ancho) quiero eliminar esos margenes de 10% a ambos lados, es decir, que su valor sea 0.

En el `@media screen` le aplico el `margin` de 0% y lo sigue dejando a 10%, no se sobreescribe, aclaro que esto no se si sea posible, sobreescribir ese valor. O que se pueda resetear y luego aplicarle el `margin` 0 pero no se como hacerlo.

Otra cosa que no se porque sucede es en la versión `desktop`, los `li` tienen un `padding left` que ni idea de donde sale, el `padding` a la izquierda que le apliqué debería ser mucho mas pequeño que el que esta mostrando ahora.

```js
let mainNav = document.getElementById("js-menu");
let navBarToggle = document.getElementById("js-navbar-toggle");

navBarToggle.addEventListener("click", function() {
  mainNav.classList.toggle("active");

});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  font-family: "Josefin Sans", sans-serif;
}

.navbar {
  font-size: 18px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border: 0px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  margin-right: 10%;
  margin-left: 10%;
}

.main-nav {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: none;
}

.nav-links,
.logo {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000000;
}

.main-nav li {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 15px auto;
}

.logo {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 22px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.navbar-toggle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #000000;
  font-size: 24px;
}

.active {
  display: block;
}

.main-nav li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.main-nav li { 
  padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
  margin: 10px 20px 10px 20px !important;
  background-color: #C4D9AE;
}


@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .navbar {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    height: 70px;
    align-items: center;
  }

  .main-nav {
    display: flex;
    margin-right: 30px;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: flex-end;
  }

  .main-nav li {
    margin: 0;
  }

  .nav-links {
    margin-left: 40px;
  }

  .logo {
    margin-top: 0;
  }

  .navbar-toggle {
    display: none;
  }

  .logo:hover,
  .nav-links:hover {
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
  }
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar">
    <span class="navbar-toggle" id="js-navbar-toggle">
            <i>X</i>
    </span>
    <a href="#" class="logo">logo</a>
    <ul class="main-nav" id="js-menu">
      <li>
        <a href="#" class="nav-links">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#" class="nav-links">Products</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#" class="nav-links">About Us</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#" class="nav-links">Contact Us</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#" class="nav-links">Blog</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
```

Comment: cambiar `min-width` por `max-width` ? el padding seguro es por el style en el ul ( le marca a los li si el bullet va dentro o fuera, de ahi que meta un padding o margin para hacerle espacio )

Comment: Intento esa recomendacion justo ahora y se invierte los diseños. El desktop se muestra a resolucion baja y el movil a resolucion alta.

Comment: el CSS va en cascada de arriba hacia abajo, si empezas con estilos mobile los vas reemplazando con min-width, si empezas con desktop los vas reemplazando con max-width

Comment: prueba poner el margin dentro del min y sacarle el important

Comment: Aparte de lo que comenta alo Malbarez (que el `min`/`max` es incorrecto), ¿dónde se están poniendo los márgenes a 0? Veo la parte del código donde se ponen a 10%, pero no parece haber ninguna donde se pongan a 0.

Comment: Si, es correcta la respuesta de @alo Malvarez, estaba maquetando en mobile sin darme cuenta que estaba invertido. Ya coloque el margin 0 fuera del media screen y funciono perfectamente.

Comment: @aloMalbarez sería interesante que agregues tu comentario como respuesta, si deseas, para futuras consultas.